# Android Device(HTC DESIRE 516) is not connecting to eclipse

Tags: android

I am trying to connect my android device to eclipse but all in vain. I have completed following tasks.

1. have enabled debugging option.
2. unknown resources enabled.
3. Installed all drivers.
4. Device is visible in system.
5. Having developer authority as well.

Actually it was getting connected when i was having android 4.0.3 but after automatic updation of my android device to 4.3 it is getting problem to connect eclipse.

Comment: Prefer Android Studio over Eclipse.. as google will stop providing support to Eclipse IDE

Comment: @N5 How to reset adb. And will it lost my all settings and data?

Comment: setting and data for? resert adb via `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`

Comment: @N5 i have tried this one as well but still didn't get any result. My device has upgraded to 4.3 it was not getting problem for android 4.0.3

Comment: so u mean adb itslef is not working? isnt it ? `adb devices` command gives none of device in console?

Comment: exactly adb device not showing any device in cmd prompt when i hit the command adb devices

Comment: may be some of dervers ur missing try `http://www.mobogenie.com/in/` it will auto detect the issues and connect ur device to android

Comment: @N5 But device is visible in system not in eclipse, i think drivers not the issue

Comment: @N5 thank you so much i solved the problem after downloading mobodenie.

Comment: @N5 as you told me about mobogenie but for this i always will be having internet connection. I think it's a bad approach. Do you have any other option as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Htc may have some drivers which may not be into your system hence you may try below 2 options :

1. Some of drivers are missing hence you can try downloading some auto-detecting drivers software like mobogenie [here](http://www.mobogenie.com/in/)
2. Visit htc site and look into derives for specfic devices.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind support.

Comment: as you told me about mobogenie but for this i always will be having internet connection. I think it's a bad approach. Do you have any other option as well?

Comment: mobogiene is just for downloading appropriate drivers, and internet is only needed for that reason, internet is not needed  for debuging

Comment: But when i used mobogenie, for that it installed all the drivers, but when internet disappears then again i faced same problem, no device connection with eclipse.

Comment: thats seems strange but i think if you download it locally , then internet will not make any issues , since i m running offline manyt times